# How is the slider build at patreon com webpage? magnifiying glass effect with preview of next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, slider

want to build a similar effect like the slider at this page. any ideas?

tried with preview images in slider..and some left rightboxes to trigger left right swipe.

Is there an example somewhere? maybe some has built something like this one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.